# IE 7 and 8 Google Website Translator fails with Error: hasOwnProperty in element.js

Tags: internet-explorer, google-translate

We use the Google website translator dropdown on several web sites. A few days ago we noticed that initializing the dropdown shows JavaScript errors on IE 7 and IE 8.

The exact source of the error is in line two of the code returned as  http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js where it says a.hasOwnProperty(b[c])?

The exact error is "Object doesn't support property or method 'hasOwnProperty'".

Strangely on one of our websites the translator dropdown does simply not show, on another one a JavaScript error is shown with every page load.

Any suggestions how to:

- Make this work for IE 7 and 8 again?
- At least avoid the JavaScript error being shown?

Is there any detailed documentation regarding the Google Website Translator or a dedicated help forum? I couldn't find anything more detailed than this: https://support.google.com/translate/#topic=2534534

Thanks

Comment: Same problem with our site.  Did not notice it before today.  Downloaded the latest snippet of code from Google, same error.

Comment: It appears to be a issue with Angular and IE11 running in IE8 compatibility mode.  Looks like Google screwed up.

Comment: I have the same issue in IE6-8. Tested on browserstack with very simple html file. It doesn't look like compatibility problem for me, as testing with 'normal' mode(compatibility is off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for cross-posting. I got some response from Google support [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-translate-api/GSWV2JL4P7I/Ek1AmJaXuGcJ) but no solution.

The issue affects IE 7 and IE 8, including running higher IE versions in compatibility mode or using the .NET Web Browser control in another program (both of which default to IE 7).

We disabled the translate utility now for IE 7 and 8 and used `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to force IE to use the latest document mode in compatibility mode and the Web Browser control (note, this does not change the user agent string in these cases, which still says MSIE 7, but runs the scripts using the latest available mode, full details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility.aspx))

Doing this we still got an "invalid parameter" error in the embedded browser control with IE 10 and IE 11, but we suppressed showing that to users by wrapping a try-catch block around the initialisation.

The full implementation of our workaround looks like this:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
   try {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-x' }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
    catch(ex) {
       //this supresses JS errors in Google code being shown to users, the translate utility will simply not be shown
    }
}

try {
    //dynamically write link to translate JS file, only if useragent is not IE 7 or IE 8 or the document mode is bigger than IE 8
    if ((navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.") == -1 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8.") == -1) || document.documentMode > 8) {       
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        newScript.src = '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';
        document.body.appendChild(newScript);
    }
} catch (ex) {
    //ignore
}
</script>
```

With this we don't bother the user with errors. Translate still fails for the embedded browsers, but if Google makes further changes there is a chance that it can still come alive again...

Answer (score 3):

Just encountered the same issue.. Seems like they are using `hasOwnProperty` which is not supported on `window` object. ([See this article](http://perrymitchell.net/article/ie8_javascript_indexof_hasownproperty/)).

> The trouble with hasOwnProperty is that it does exist in
>   IE8, but is not usable on the window object. If you’ve gone and
>   written tonnes of code using commands like
>   ‘window.hasOwnProperty(“somevar”)’, you might break down at the sight
>   of it all failing in IE8. There’s a nice little fix for this:

use the following code to fix the problem.

```
window.hasOwnProperty = window.hasOwnProperty || Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
```

Hopefully, it might fix the problem on IE7 too.